# Riding/beating a dead horse

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead, mount

Context:  My Undead Lord Cleric's current Corpse Companion is a [fast zombie](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/zombie#TOC-Fast-Zombie-CR-0-) [heavy horse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/horse/heavy-horse).

So, my GM and I disagree on a key aspect of riding an undead horse.  He thinks that because riding a living horse is about as tiring as jogging, it should be the same on the undead horse.  I agree that riding a living horse is tiring, but the work the jockey has to put into riding the living horse is a) to keep from tiring the horse out prematurely and b) to prevent the rider's weight injuring the horse, neither of which should apply to the abomination against nature my character is riding.

Oddly enough, I believe the rules are already in my favor, because normal riding doesn't appear to take actions and therefore shouldn't be tiring at all, allowing me to go on only obeying the rules for the need for sleep; but it's very rare I do anything with mounts in my own games and I'm pretty rusty.

(Because I can be a bit of a rules-lawyer, here are some specific things this question is *not* about:  Rule Zero, whether a fast zombie can be a corpse companion, whether an undead horse can count as "war-trained".)

Comment: What rules do you follow for riding at the moment? I think most groups don't track this sort of thing, just assume that you can have "a day's ride" and be able to fight as normal, but don't take the piss and march/ride for 16 hours straight expecting no downsides.

I don't see any reason a zombie horse would be less tiring than a normally trained horse, it might be like riding a motorbike -- it does all the work, but you still have to balance and cushion yourself!

(Admittedly, most campaigns assume normally-trained horses, riding a BADLY trained horse is more tiring!)

Comment: You could always cast overland flight on both you and the horse and tie a rope to it around your waist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The horse does not get tired. It doesn't necessarily mean that YOU don't get tired. You're still going be bouncing up and down (unless you've ALSO fused with the horse). You still have to guide the horse (more so, in this case, because your horse can't think). You have to stay ON the horse. It won't try to throw you, but it's still moving very fast. It's not just dragging you along in a carriage, so why wouldn't you get saddle-sore?

Comment: @gatherer818 All that stuff isn't just to avoid injuring or tiring the horse. It's also to keep you from falling off or sustaining saddle-inflicted injuries. The mount being undead saves you not at all from riding fatigue inflicted by its gait and using the muscles needed to keep yourself stable atop it. (I recommend becoming a lich to properly avoid these inconveniences.)

Comment: it wouldn't be unreasonable to just assume that it's not substantially more or less tiring for the rider to ride an undead horse as a living one, on grounds of is it even worth applying that level of granularity for this?

Comment: +1 I would like to add, that even if he _was_ fused with the horse, he would likely tire anyway, just a little bit less. Unless he himself was undead, but then it would be a moot point.

Comment: In real life it is possible to sleep on a horse without getting hurt, and historically was done relatively commonly.  Saddle sores usually take a lot of time in the saddle for experienced riders with proper fitting saddles.  The real problem is that horses can't see at night.

Answer (score 6):

There aren't any rules regarding how tired the *rider* gets from [riding overland](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/movement#TOC-Mounted-Movement) in PF. **Therefore, you don't get tired when riding overland in PF, by RAW.** Obviously [regular rest rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Rest) apply. Your GM is free to change that by fiat, which you are free to take issue with. You should be able to gallop a horse into the ground, and be fresh as a daisy by the end, provided you make the Ride/Acrobatics check to land safely.

You didn't ask this part, but I think it's worth talking about the mechanics of an undead mount.

So your [Fast Zombie](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/zombie#TOC-Fast-Zombie-CR-0-) [Horse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/horse/heavy-horse) is 22 STR, land speed 60, no con (NOT 0, thanks), Immune to fatigue, exhaustion and non-lethal damage. It's light load limit is 519 lbs, and it isn't staggered. Depending on rule interpretation:

1) More RAW based

Your undead horse, which doesn't have a metabolism and belongs to a creature type known for being tireless, [inexplicably takes lethal damage when moving at a hustle overland](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/movement#TOC-Mounted-Movement). It probably fails most of it's CON checks because it [uses it's 10 CHA](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Undead) for this purpose. At least it isn't fatigued.

[When trying to Run](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Run), it can run 0 rounds before it has to make a DC 10+1 per round check to "keep running" with a +0. When it fails, it has to rest a round before trying again. Again, it can't be fatigued.

2) More common sense based (because the RAW is implicitly concerned with living creatures who are subject to fatigue and have a metabolism)

Your undead horse can move 240 ft/rd (27 mph) without damage until it's destroyed or you tell it to stop. Your range is limited by your occasional need to get off and sleep. It wouldn't take non-lethal damage, so it stands to reason it wouldn't take exertion-based lethal damage. It can run infinite rounds, since it's CON is -.

Which interpretation you use is a matter for you and your GM.

Comment: I like when people give numbers in answers like this.